# GenyMotion: Basic understanding

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, simulator, genymotion

OK so I am trying out Genymotion for testing my app, so that I can reproduce the errors that my users are telling me they experience with my app, which leads me to fixing the issues. I guess that is the main reason for using Genymotion.

Real life example:

A guy says: "I'm using a Moto X (2013) on Android 5.1.1 and I can't do X with your app.

Me: Looks at Genymotions list of virtual devices and can't find neither the brand of phone nor the android system. I can only find android 5.1.0.

Does this mean that I Genymotion just doesn't have what I need, or is it because one of the other options are just as good? I really don't know. What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.
Brian

Comment: Genymotion, like the AVD Manager, simply tries to replicate the device features. Such as it's RAM, screen size. Even the device frame (_if possible and available_). So if you don't see a device listed, it simply means that a template of _X_ device is not available. That being said, you can always recreate the device spec as much as possible. Simply look up the specs online and use them to configure your Genymotion emulator. For example: http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Motorola-Moto-X_id7885 lists the specs for the Moto X

Comment: Having said the above, an emulator, Genymotion or others, will, IMO, never replicate a physical device in the _truest sense_.

Answer (score -1):

An emulator, be it the default android emulator or Genymotion or any other emulator will not be able to replicate a real physical device to the complete extent.

The devices available on Genymotion are just templates to recreate the device with values such as RAM, Screen size etc. You could try creating a custom device by using the values for Moto X.

One possible idea would be to get the stacktrace from your friend and see what's going on. The best way to do that would be to integrate crash reporting system like [Crashyltics](https://crashlytics.com). You will automatically get crash reports in your [fabric dashboard](http://fabric.io).